# cURL working on localhost but not on live website

Tags: curl

I have a small piece of script to grab images from a different website, works perfectly in localhost but does not work on on the live website.

According to the phpinfo() on the site CURL is enabled.

I can't post the script as its sensitive - But off the top of your head what things should I check for to solve this issue? Why would CURL work on localhost and other hosts, but not with others that also have CURL supposedly enabled?

Comment: unless we see yur script / output , how are we supposed to comment

Comment: Thats why I asked for "off the top of your head" :) sorry. I was hoping someone would atleast have some advice to guide towards potential problems.

Comment: check if the telnet is working , I guess that the firewall is not allowing